# BrilliantRetail->checkout_shipping action network FAILURE

Tags: shipping, brilliantretail

In one of my dev environments, I'm having an issue with loading Shipping Rates.

I have action 39, checkout shipping in BrilliantRetail.
When I go to the checkout page, the loading.gif spins, then nothing. The network debugging tool in Chrome just shows FAILURE for every "?ACT=39" call.

Any ideas on what to check? The same code is being used in several different dev environments and a production site with no problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its hard to say what the local issue would be without any additional information, but here are a few things you might try:

- Is the request locally going to the correct url? Ajax will fail if for cross domain issues. Make sure the url is exactly the same as the one requested.
- Make sure that you aren't trying to hit an "https" url locally if you do not have an SSL certificate installed. That will throw an SSL error and result in an ajax failure.

Comment: Even removing the UPS and USPS shipping methods and enabling ONLY Free Shipping, it still occurs.